Ubuntu 24.04 booting process stopped to work
My computer with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS stopped to boot. Immediately after upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1 LTas I I started to observe a bunch of bugs. And now this happened. I got stuck in this window, as shown in screenshot.
I can reach tty, but have no clue what to do, or what should be wrong. I found post about event 0x02 and follow it up.
What should I check next?
Any help would be very welcome.
Thanks 


Reboot into grub menu and select advanced-options->recovery-mode and see if you can boot to the GUI. The debugging lines you report suggest (to me) you might have a comms driver problem. If you don't have a grub menu boot with ESC key asserted repeatably (UEFI) or SHIFT key asserted repeatably (MBR).

I reached grub, and command line.
I also managed to fix the issue,
SOLUTION: sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session.
Long story short:
I wanted to try out Cursor AI coding tool via .AppImage. To run it I missed some packages including fuse3. In my case fuse3 was causing an error.
Thanks to Reddit where I found the command -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1c769sx/kauditd_printk_skb_140_callback_suppressed/
